We draw a ball, look at it, then return it to the urn and add another ball of the same color. Pr: "after $n$ draws the urn contains $j$ white balls"?
The urn contains $1$ white ball and $1$ black ball. We make a sequence of $n$ draws according to the following scheme: we draw a ball, look at it, then return it to the urn and add another ball of the same color. For $j \in \{ 1, 2, . . . , n + 1 \}$, let $p_j$ denote the probability that after $n$ draws the urn contains exactly $j$ white balls. Prove that $p_j = \frac{1}{n + 1}$ for all $j$.

I came up with a recoursive equation describing the number of white balls after n draws.

$\mathbb{P}_1(j,n) =$ probability that after $n$ draws we have $j$ white balls in the urn,
$\mathbb{P}_2(b, n-1) =$ probability, that after $n-1$ draws we will draw a black ball from the urn.

The equation goes like this:
$$\mathbb{P}_1(j,n) = \mathbb{P}_2(b, n-1) \cdot \mathbb{P}_1(j,n-1) + \mathbb{P}_2(w, n-1) \cdot \mathbb{P}_1(j-1,n-1)$$
$$\mathbb{P}_1(j,n) = \frac{n-1+2-j}{n-1+2} \mathbb{P}_1(j,n-1) + \frac{j-1}{n-1+2} \mathbb{P}_1(j-1,n-1)$$
$$\mathbb{P}(j,n)_1 = \frac{n-j+1}{n+1} \mathbb{P}_1(j,n-1) + \frac{j-1}{n+1} \mathbb{P}_1(j-1,n-1)$$
Now I would like to substitute the assumed formula: $\mathbb{P}_1(j,n) = \frac{1}{n + 1}$ and check the result, but I can't since we have $\mathbb{P}_1(j-1,n-1)$ in the equation and I don't know how to evaluate that.
Anybody knows how to do that?

I don't like your notation! Given $\mathbb{P}(x,y)$ , how do we know whether it means the first or the second of your $\mathbb P$'s? Better would be $\mathbb{P}_1(j,n)$ and $\mathbb{P}_2(n)$.

Yeah, you are right. I'm sorry. I will make that more clear in a moment.

@TonyK Is that any better now? I edited my questen but I'm not sure if that's the way you suggested.

Your definition of $\Bbb P_2$ is wrong. From what I can deduce, you mean $\Bbb P_2(c,n) =$ probability of drawing a ball of colour $c$ from the urn after $n$ draws.

There are basically two approaches to solve your problem. One approach is to formulate a $2D$ recursion. It is very tedious to solve it that way. I'll share another solution, which simplifies it and helps in appreciating the problem on a deeper level.
For any $j \in \{ 1, 2, . . . , n + 1 \}$, for any permutation $\pi$ of W and B balls to achieve $j$ number of white balls,  denote $P(j, \pi)$ = Probability of the urn containing $j$ white balls by the permutation $\pi$, where $\pi$ is a permutation of $W$ and $B$ of size $n$ having $(j-1)$ number of $W's$ and $(n - j + 1)$ number of $B's$  .
Claim$1$: $P(j ,\pi)$ is independent of $\pi$
Consider $n = 100$, $j = 5$. Let's calculate $P(5, \pi_1)$ where $\pi_1 = WWWWBBBBB....B$. $$P(5, \pi_1) = \frac12 \cdot \frac23 \cdot \frac34 \cdot \frac45 \cdot \frac16 \cdot \frac27 \cdot \frac38 \cdot \frac49 \cdot ... \cdot \frac{96}{101} = \frac{4! \cdot 96!}{101!} = \big({101} \cdot {100 \choose 4}\big)^{-1}$$
Calculate $P(5, \pi)$ for any other possible $\pi$ leading to $j = 5$, notice that the only thing that varies is the order in which the numbers occur in the numerator. This argument can be extended to any $j$. Thus $$P(j,\pi_1) = P(j, \pi_2) = ... = P(j, \pi_k) = \big((n+1)\cdot{n \choose j - 1} \big)^{-1}$$
Claim$2$: $P(j)$ is independent of $j$, in particular, $P(j) = \frac{1}{n + 1}$
Consider the same example as in Claim$1$. How many different $\pi_i's$ are possible for $n = 100, j = 5$?
It is of course, the number of ways to choose $4$ objects from $100$, i.e. $100 \choose 4$. From Claim$1$ each of these is equally likely. Hence, for $n = 100, P(5) = {100 \choose 4} \cdot \big({101} \cdot {100 \choose 4}\big)^{-1}  = \frac{1}{101}$.
Generalising, the number of different $\pi_i's$ for $n, j = {n \choose j - 1}$, each of which is equally likely by Claim$1$, hence:
$$P(j) = {n \choose j-1 } \cdot P(j, \pi_i)$$
$$=> P(j) = {n \choose j-1 } \cdot \big((n+1)\cdot{n \choose j - 1} \big)^{-1}$$
$$=>\boxed{ P(j) = \frac{1}{n + 1}}$$

What do you mean by "j no of white balls"? Does it mean "j number of balls"?

no is short for number. I made the edit in my answer to avoid confusion.

Ok, then in second paragraph you write that $P(j, \pi)$ is the probability of the urn containing j white balls by permutation $\pi$ and that $\pi$ is a permutation of size $n$ having $j-1$ white balls... so how many white balls does permutation $\pi$ contain? $j$ or $j-1$?

I am defining my permutation $\pi$ by excluding the first white and the first black balls. Thus $\pi$ is essentially a string of length $n$ and not $n+2$. See the example I mentioned. In order to obtain $5$ white balls in the case where $n = 100$, I have my $\pi_1$ containing $4 W's$ and $96 B's.$

$\pi$ contains $j-1$ W's but actually counts the case where $j$ number of white balls are obtained. If this is confusing I can edit the answer and include the two balls already present in the urn within the definition of $\pi$

No, no, thanks. Now I get it. Sorry for confusion, you are right - there were 2 balls already inside of the urn.

I think I understand it now. Thank you!

Check out this problem. Your problem is basically the same problem but reframed. The basketball being scored in the original problem is analogous to a white ball being drawn, and a miss is analogous to a black ball being drawn.
Note that in the original problem, the probability of scoring is proportional to the number of goals scored. In your problem as well, the probability of adding a ball of a particular colour is proportional to the number of balls of that colour already present in the urn as well.
Thus the two problems are equivalent.
The only minor difference is in the definition of n. In the original problem the value of n includes the first two shots hence the no of scores varies from $1, 2, 3, ..., n - 1$. Hence $P$(scoring k shots) = $\frac{1}{n-1}$.
Whereas in your problem the n draws are made after the first two balls are put in, hence, the no of white balls that can be there in the urn after all the draws have been made varies from $1, 2, 3, ..., n + 1$.
Thus P(no of white balls = $j$) = $\frac1{n+1}$
Note: In order to understand how the $2D$ recurrence is formed you can read this answer to the original problem. In order to understand how it is to be solved (without induction), you can have look at this answer to my question regarding the same.

Just by the first look at it - the answer for the question is $\frac{1}{n-1}$. The answer for my question is to be $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

In the basketball problem, scoring any k number of goals is equally probable. Since total number of goals that can be scored i.e. k can be 1,2,... or 99, Hence P(k) = $\frac{1}{99}$. In your problem, the number of white balls can be 1, 2, ..., n + 1, each being equally probable. Hence, P = $\frac{1}{n+1}$

Let me know if you have trouble understanding the equivalence. I'll write another answer explaining the approach from scratch for your problem.

Hmm, I need some time to think about it and probably write an answer to my question myself. If I see that all organized for my particular problem and don't see any flaws I will be sure. If you have some time for that you can show me that in another answer as well - I will mark it as the correct one then. Anyway, thank you for help :)

Please check out my new answer, I hope it suffices.
